# Cycle using method in CoffeeScript

Tags: for-loop, coffeescript, prototypejs

Given I have two objects `lower` and `upper` of same type and they return successive value using method `succ` (as in ruby) and can be compared using `<`.

In plain javascript I can write:

```
for (var i = lower; i <= upper; i = i.succ()) {
  // …
}
```

Using prototype I can write shorter:

```
$R(lower, upper).each(function(i){
  // …
}, this)
```

Using prototype in coffeescript I can write even shorter:

```
$R(lower, upper).each (i)->
  # …
, this
```

But without prototype, I found only this way to do same thing:

```
i = lower
while i <= upper
  # …
  i = i.succ()
```

Is there anything shorter?

Comment: I think that should be `while i < upper`, if you want it to be equivalent to a `for` with an end condition of `i < upper`.

Comment: Or, since [Prototype's $R is inclusive by default](http://prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-r), your `for` should have `i <= upper` to make all of your code snippets equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct that

```
i = lower
while i < upper
  # …
  i = i.succ()
```

is the shortest way to write this without using a function. Of course, you could write such a function without using Prototype:

```
eachSucc = (lower, upper, func) ->
  i = lower
  while i < upper
    func i
    i = i.succ()
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
eachSucc lower, upper, (i) -> ...
```

Comment: Yes, but I really like that CoffeeScript allows to write short code that don't need to use anonymous functions (also binding is sometimes required).

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while upper >= n = i.succ()
  alert n
```

Try it [here](http://tinkerbin.com/zGxVUh4a), for the example I used the following fixture:

```
upper = 3
lower = 0

counter = (l) ->
  _ = l
  -> _++

i = succ: counter(lower)
```

/me still wishing for widespread [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.7) support in Javascript..